# Issue in sharing customer accounts globally

Tags: customer, magento-1.8, multistore, currency, customer-account

- We have a magento installation and **three websites** with one store and store view each.

  - mywebsite.com/
  - mywebsite.com/store2/
  - mywebsite.com/store3/
- Each website have different currencies.
- **Share Customer Accounts** is set to **Global** under System->CUSTOMERS->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Options.

Now if a customer login at mywebsite.com/ and then go to other two websites he/she is logged in that website also, which is working as intended.

But if they login into mywebsite.com/store2/ or mywebsite.com/store3/, and then switch websites, they have to login again, why is this so?

Is this a bug? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a problem with cookies here.

If you login on the path "/" the cookie is accessible on all sub paths.
of you login on "/store2/" it is only accessible on "/store2/" and sub paths, so its not accessible from "/" or "/store3/".

There should be a way to force the cookie domain/path, so every store writes to the cookie to "/"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

Comment: that's right, i'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem is here [Magento Multiple Website Store - Login](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-multiple-website-login#more-3047).

This allows you to login from anywhere under your domain which will reflect beyond it's scope. This solves the issue mentioned by FlyningMana.